# Load Only First Tab's Fragment of viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am using TabLayout with Viewpager and having 3 tabs. I am using FragmentPagerAdapter to set the tabs and it's fragments.

I want to load only first tab's fragment when it is selected by default and want to load other tab's fragment in a new activity.

I have tried to return null when from getItem method in case of position 1 and 2 but it gives exception.

How can I do this, can you please help me here.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: Why would you "want to load other tab's fragment in a new activity"?

Comment: Actually in my activity I am having a lot of textviews, images then below that view having these tabs which are almost at the end of the view, so for better clarity to show content clearly I want these fragments to be loaded in a new activity. Please help me if you have any idea here.

Comment: You have subclassed FragmentPagerAdapter? As a nested class in activies or as a public class?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `FragmentPagerAdapter` you typically extend it and Override a couple of methods. One of them is `getItemCount()`. Simply make this return 1 or 3 (or whatever) depending on the hosting `Activity`. For example, pass the hosting `Activity` as a parameter and check which `Activity` class is the host of your tabs in the `getItemCount()` method.

You could also add your own method `public void setItemCount(int count)` that will change the amount of tabs shown (and `Fragment`s loaded). But I am not sure if this will work.